# Regarding text-align

Tags: javascript, text, onclick, alignment

been working on a site recently and wanted to adjust it so that it would have the picture followed by text to the right giving a brief description.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function gotofirst()
    {
    alert('This link will be replaced with the appropiate link');
    window.open('http://google.com');
    }
</script>

<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/poster2.jpg" onClick="gotosecond()">
    </td>
    <p id="forum">Join us on our forums, chat with staff members and much more!</p>

</tr>
```

CSS:

```
#forum
{
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Then have the CSS file to right-align. Problem is that the image gets pushed down and the text doesn't squeeze in the provided box instead it right-aligns ABOVE the image when I want it to the right.

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/HCVVp/

Thanks

Comment: show css too. better if you will upload code to jsfiddle

Comment: Please consider creating a [testcase](http://cssdeck.com/labs).

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work properly. Provide some valid code, please, there are too many trivial errors

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/poster2.jpg" onClick="gotosecond()" style="float:left;display:block">
        <p id="forum" style="float:right">Join us on our forums, chat with staff members and much more!</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

if it still does not work, try wrapping inside a div

```
<tr>
        <td>
           <div>
            <img src="images/poster2.jpg" onClick="gotosecond()" style="float:left;display:block">
            <p id="forum" style="float:right">Join us on our forums, chat with staff members and much more!</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: The image is now on top and the text is underneath. I'm trying to keep the image to the left and text to the right

Comment: Both answers gave me the same output. The image on top followed by the text on bottom

Comment: it should work. I just tried it. Are you sure you have enough space to display the text to the right?

Comment: @JuxhinDyrmishiBrigjaj: Please always mark answers that help you as accepted. People here will help you more if your previous questions have accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you that not use  elements whenever possible. I think you could do somehing like that:

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="images/poster2.jpg" onClick="gotosecond()">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p id="forum">Join us on our forums, chat with staff members and much more!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right}
```

Another solution is removing the div's and apply the `.left` and `.right` classes only to the `<img>` and `<p>` elements.

Comment: This approach seems verbose : float:left and float:right are duplicated

Comment: You are right! I forgot to remove the styles inside the img and p tags! Thnks! :)

Comment: p is already a block element, why do we need to wrap it inside a div?

Comment: Don't need it. So I comented that another solution is removing the div. It's only that I sometimes (depending of code) prefer to put div that contents <p> elements until put <p> elements without a div that contains it. I think is an infatuation devs.

Comment: I fixed some things, You can see the result here http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/7erwf/

Comment: Dude, check the question as solved. People with the same question may helped by us in the futuer ;)